# Disable Form after Successful form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

We're having problems with an open source third party application. Many of the forms take awhile to submit and people are pressing the 'submit' button multiple times. Many of these forms are already using onsubmit to validate the forms. We don't want to harm any of that.

At first, we thought we could just disable submit buttons once clicked. The problem is if the form doesn't validate, then the button is still disabled.

We also can't just use a basic onsubmit because we would overwrite the current validation and other processes.

Is there a way that we can disable the submit button only after validatation when the form actually begins successful submission?

Comment: Can you post code (or more information) about the eventHandler for the form's onsubmit event? If there is a returned value from the function that validates, you could just create a wrapper function that would still execute the current eventHandler and possibly re-enable the form if the validation function returns information.

Comment: I intentionally did not post any code as I am dealing with a generic situation in the purest sense. As this is a 3rd party solution with many variances, I need a solution that will work across the many forms in the application regardless of their javascript validations.

Comment: Well if you have to take a "black box" view of current event handlers, you are pretty much limited to either wrapping them in a function you create, or not using the current event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then call your validate function and if it fails just reenable the button.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no control over the third-party app, one approach may be to disable each button on click, and then re-enable that button after a certain period – long enough for the validate routine to complete.  If the validate function is successful, the form will submit, at which point there's no button *to* re-enable.

This should get you going:

```
$('button').on('click',function() {
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
  (function(b) {
     setTimeout(function() {
       b.prop('disabled', false);
     },1000);
   }
  )($(this));
});
```

Fiddle:  **http://jsfiddle.net/x3tv6vqo/**